# Equal width + height responsive divs with hover overlay

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover, responsive

I'm having trouble getting the heights on my divs to match up. I need them to match the heights of the div with the most content - which is normally easy BUT I'm doing this with overlays that also contain more text. I can't do it with fixed heights or widths because I need the layout to be responsive. The cells need to basically be col-md-2 with the tallest height as the text wraps, it would be more like a square, col-sm-6 would be long and narrow, and col-xs-12 would also be long and narrow.

[image]

It doesn't HAVE to be bootstrap, but it needs to have that effect. The other kicker is that I need to do as much of this inline as possible, because I'm delivering it to a client to paste into their drupal site without having much access to the backend, so please ignore my gross inline code.

I've almost got it, the overlays work, and the heights are being determined by the content, but I just can't get the heights to match up to the longest one. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here??

```css
#table{ 
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
.tr{ 
    display: table-row; 
}
.td{ 
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    }
    

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align: middle;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/fullwidth-small.png');
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: 500% auto;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.overlay:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 1;
}

.text:hover {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
 
}

.cell {
  font-size: 14px;
  
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="table" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="td col-md-12" style="background-image: url('https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/fullwidth-small.png');
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: 500% auto;  text-align: center; padding-top: 10%; padding-bottom: 10%">test</div>
    </div>
   
<div id="table">    
   

 
    
        <div class="td col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" 
        style="color: #0169A9;  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 6px #0169A9; -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 6px #0169A9;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 6px #0169A9;       font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    line-height: 1.2;">To find out more about the making of this toolkit, click here
        <div class="overlay text">
         Test this
      </div>
      </div>
      
      
      
        <div class="td col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"  style="color: #0169A9;  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 6px #0169A9; -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 6px #0169A9;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 6px #0169A9;       font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    line-height: 1.2;">To find out more about the making of this toolkit
        <div class="overlay text">
         Test this
      </div>
      </div>
        
        
        <div class="td col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"  style="color: #0169A9;  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 6px #0169A9; -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 6px #0169A9;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 6px #0169A9;       font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    line-height: 1.2;">To find out more about the making of this toolkit, click here toolkit, click here
        <div class="overlay text">
         Test this
      </div>
      </div>
        
        
        
       <div class="td col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"  style="color: #0169A9;  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 6px #0169A9; -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 6px #0169A9;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 6px #0169A9;       font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    line-height: 1.2;">To find out more about the making of this toolkit, click here
        <div class="overlay text">
         Test this
      </div>
      </div>
        
        
        
       <div class="td col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"  style="color: #0169A9;  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 6px #0169A9; -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 6px #0169A9;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 6px #0169A9;       font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    line-height: 1.2;">To find out more about the making of this toolkit, click here
        <div class="overlay text">
         Test this
      </div>
      </div>
        
        
       
        <div class="clear-all">
         </div>

    
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: make an array with jquery, storing all heights of a row, then set dynamically a fixed height equals to the max one. You can repeat this job on $(window).resize() event  to keep the responsiveness.

Comment: Can you explain further? I am not familiar enough with jquery to know how to implement this suggestion.  The client will be changing the text within the divs so I will not know fixed height of any of them at any time. Also Keep in mind that I don't have access to any of the backend files, I can add some css in the css designer on my client's drupal site, but I don't know about jquery. Is it possible?

Comment: if there's any plug-in to it, maybe. Anyway you've to edit the public side, not the backend. It's always more difficult when there's a CMS between you and what you want to reach...

Comment: i mean to read all .md-2 heights, then, select the max value, and set it as fixed height for all others. You can repeat this function depending on the event listener you want to trigger it. You can even use plain javascript if you want.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: done :) check the answer and apply to your project, if you need an explanation tell me and i can comment code, but it's simply a nested jQuery .each so you can find all info on jQuery doc. Hope it helps

Comment: and please, don't perform styling on html style attribute, it's highly not recommended

Comment: I know "The other kicker is that I need to do as much of this inline as possible, because I'm delivering it to a client to paste into their drupal site without having much access to the backend, so please ignore my gross inline code."

Comment: this is not a reason to clean the code before providing it to fix an issue or, in this case, help you to learn and understand how you can deal with your actual problem, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry i was busy, here's a working example:

```js
//we need to iterate through row childs
$('.row').each(function() {
    //Set a var to store the highest height
    var maxHeight = 0;
    //Then, we iterate through all cols inside the row, searching for the highest one.
    $('.col-xs-4', this).each(function() {
        if($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
         maxHeight = $(this).height();  
        }
    });
    //Now, we have the height value of the highest one, so we can apply this height to all row childs.
    $('.col-xs-4', this).each(function() {
        $(this).height(maxHeight); 
     });
});
```

```css
.col-xs-4{
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried adding using this with my current setup to accommodate the hover overlay, but it doesn't seem to be working. See, with my example, the table div is fitting to the correct height, but the overlay is not stretching to the entire length. I tried implementing your code, but I don't think I know enough about javascript to have done it right.
https://jsfiddle.net/graphicfixations/0vhsu5ce/30/

Comment: first of all you're repeating ID tag on divs, your IDE should pointed out this big error, then, you're using $('.table') which is a class selector, instead of using $('#table') (id selector) but it will not work because we need classes to deal with it. Then, your code is too tidy, move your css to css part, letting the html clean, i can't read it properly and my eyes are bleeding... :V

Comment: I know, I hate coding inline, but the client doesn't have access to anything so I need to do as much of it this way as possible. Let me move it back over for this example. I'm not working in an IDE I'm just hand coding in jsfiddle. I totally spaced on that. hang on.

Comment: Ok, code cleaned and separated and I fixed the issue with the ID tags. Would you mind taking a look now? I promise, no more eye bleeding. https://jsfiddle.net/graphicfixations/0vhsu5ce/70/

Comment: That's gorgeous!  Any way to get the text to center properly using that fix?

Comment: I think there's an issue with the responsiveness of this - when I reduce the screen width and then enlarge it again, the boxes to not resize to fit the contents and the text gets cut off...

Comment: you need to trigger it when window resize, let me dit

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0vhsu5ce/81/ . edited. Yes, you can run with it to get text center but you'll need to recalculate it different. To get the text centered you can use pure CSS. And, please mark it as solved, patch your project and if you need, add another question about text-centering with CSS. Good luck in your projects! :)